# Java Spring inline text editor

Tags: java, wordpress, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm not sure they are called `inline text editor` but I want something like this in wordpress:

[image]

(not necessary with add media)

So I can get the html text and save it to my database. Where can I find something like this and use it in my project?

PS: My project is developed in Spring MVC

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).  You should be able to incorporate that into Spring MVC

Comment: awesome, very easy to integrate it. Thanks, it was exactly what I needed.